# Can't run docker - repository does not exist

Tags: windows, docker

I have created a `Dockerfile` in my file structure, built a docker repository, and tried to run it, but I keep getting the following error:

`Error response from daemon: repository not found, does not exist, or no pull access`.

I'm pretty new to docker, so what could possibly be wrong here?

Commands I run:

```
docker build -t repoName .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 repoName
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.10.3

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Setup enviromnet
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl tar
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Do some building and copying

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/sh", "/app/run-dockerized.sh"]
```

Comment: Is it building? Is it nginx it can't find or your built one? Can you post the output of the build?